# Cannot resolve the problem of not opening miniedit in mininet

Tags: networking, network-programming, mininet, sdn, openflow

I have problem opening miniedit file, it was working for me two days ago and I have no idea what change I have made it is not waorking today.
Here is my command:

```
➜  examples git:(master) python3 miniedit.py
```

But I get StrictVersion error in `mininet.util`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pooya/mininet/examples/miniedit.py", line 28, in <module>
    from mininet.util import (netParse, ipAdd, quietRun,
ImportError: cannot import name 'StrictVersion' from 'mininet.util' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mininet/util.py)
```

I already update and upgrade. Plus I tried

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

and remove and re-install mininet but seeing same result each and every time.

Comment: Ok, It's not the answer for why I face the problem in python3 over the command `python3 miniedit.py` but here I solved my problem by just running python2 instead of 3 and I guess maybe Its a dependency not installed in python3 or something. But hope if someone has faced the same problem answer for future info.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the original source code of miniedit.py on https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/examples/miniedit.py . See the line 28 where there is an import from mininet.util which contains a StrictVersion parameter. Our error is being generated due to this. Thus, navigate to the mininet directory where miniedit.py file is located. Open it using a text editor like gedit and remove the parameter of StrictVersion. If it is explicitly mentioned in the file for import StrictVersion, remove that also. Try to run miniedit.py using python command and it might remove the issue. It worked for me!